# What is the WSO2 ESB message processor method performed after that an element is retrieved from a message store and before the sequence execution?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am pretty new in **WSO2 ESB** and I have the following problem trying to create a custom message processor which extends the WSO2 **SamplingProcessor** class.

The **SamplingProcessor** class extends the **ScheduledMessageProcessor** abstract class which in turn implements the **MessageProcessor** interface (so I think that it should contain the list of all methods that can be implemented by a message processor.

So, to implement my custom message processor, I created a **Maven** project using this **pom.xml** file (it should fit the requirement to build a custom message processor):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.toolkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>Sampling Processor Header Rate Limitation</name>
    <description>Custom Sampling Mesageprocessor using response header to implement the rate limitation</description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor</Bundle-Name>
                        <Export-Package>com.mycompany.toolkit.*</Export-Package>
                        <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                        <Scm-Root>${project.scm.connection}</Scm-Root>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <id>wso2-nexus</id>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <id>wso2-nexus</id>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
            <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7-wso2v3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <CApp.type>lib/synapse/mediator</CApp.type>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Then I created this SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation that is my custom message processor implementation and that extends the SamplingProcessor WSO2 message processor class:

```
package com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.synapse.SynapseException;
import org.apache.synapse.core.SynapseEnvironment;
import org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor;
import org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessor;
import org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessorView;

public class SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation extends SamplingProcessor {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ScheduledMessageProcessor.class.getName());
    private SamplingProcessorView view;

    @Override
    public void init(SynapseEnvironment se) {
        super.init(se);

        logger.info("init() START");
        System.out.println("init() START");

        try {
            view = new SamplingProcessorView(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SynapseException(e);
        }

        // register MBean
        org.apache.synapse.commons.jmx.MBeanRegistrar.getInstance().registerMBean(view,
                "Message Sampling Processor view", getName());

        logger.info("init() END");
        System.out.println("init() END");
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameters(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        logger.info("setParameters() START");
        System.out.println("setParameters() START");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setParameters(parameters);

        logger.info("setParameters() END");
        System.out.println("setParameters() END");
    }
}
```

Finnally I am using my custom **SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation** class into the ESB message processor definition (instead of the standard SamplingProcessor):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!---<messageProcessor class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessor" messageStore="transferFromMessageStore" name="transferFromMessageProcessor" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">-->
<messageProcessor class="com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor.SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation" messageStore="transferFromMessageStore" name="transferFromMessageProcessor" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="sequence">transferProcessorSequence</parameter>
    <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
    <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="concurrency">1</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

This message processor perform the **transferProcessorSequence.xml** sequence for each element retrieved from the **transferFromMessageStore** message store.

It works fine but as you can see I put some **logger.info()** into the **init()** and **setParameters()** methods of my custom implementation. It works fine but these method are performed only once when the message processor is initialized.

I need to know what is the method that is performed each time that an element is retrieved from the **transferFromMessageStore** message store because here I have to implement a custom operation.

So, what is the method performed after that an element is retrieved from the message store related to a message processor and before the execution of the related sequence? (it is very important to me know the method after the retrieving of the element and before the sequence execution)

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to do custom implementation between every message consumption and dispatch to the sequence, need to extend the class SamplingService. `org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingService.java`

Because its the `org.apache.synapse.task.Task`associated with SamplingService Processor.

Need to override either `execute()` or `fetch(MessageConsumer msgConsumer)` method in SamplingService. preferably `fetch` method. Also have a look at `dispatch()` method of the service.

```
public MessageContext fetch(MessageConsumer msgConsumer) {
MessageContext newMsg = super.fetch(msgConsumer);
// custom code here
return newMsg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com Luke

[MessageProcessor code on github](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/message/processor/MessageProcessor.java)

important lines are:

```
boolean setMessageConsumer(MessageConsumer messageConsumer);
List<MessageConsumer> getMessageConsumer();
```

Documentation of method *setMessageConsumer*, clearly states.

> ```
> /**
>  * This method is used to set the message consumer of message processor. Consumer is the one who is
>  * responsible for retrieving messages from a store.
>  * @param messageConsumer is the name of the associated message consumer
>  * @return is true if the message if the message consumer is returned successfully. Otherwise false.
>  */
> ```

Since storing and consuming messages from store are opposite operation, then all those java classes should be next to each other. All you need, must be around same folder.